# Parsing scheme dottedlist/list with Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, scheme, parsec

I am following [this guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing%20this%20guide) on writing a scheme interpreter. In trying to left-factor the grammar for DottedList/List, I came up with this:

```
E -> (H T)
H -> E H'
H' -> <space> H
H' -> <term>
T ->  <term>
T -> <space> . <space> E
```

--

```
spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = skipMany1 (space <?> "spaces")

parseExpr :: Parser LispVal
parseExpr = (... omitted ...) <|>
             do char '('
                h <- sepBy parseExpr spaces
                t <- optionMaybe ((spaces' >> char '.' >> spaces' >> parseExpr)  <?> "parseDotExpr failed")
                z <- if isJust t then return $ DottedSuffix $ fromJust t else return Tail
                z' <- case z of Tail           -> return $ List x
                                DottedSuffix s -> return $ DottedList x s
                char ')'
                return z'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't handle the basic dottedlists:

```
test/Spec.hs:23: 
1) test eval 1 evals DottedList
     expected: "(1 2 . 1)"
      but got: "Parse error at \"lisp\" (line 1, column 7):\nunexpected \".\"\nexpecting spaces' or parseExpr!"

test/Spec.hs:26: 
2) test eval 1 evals DottedList (quoted)
     expected: "((1 2) . 1)"
      but got: "Parse error at \"lisp\" (line 1, column 15):\nunexpected \".\"\nexpecting spaces' or parseExpr!"

test/Spec.hs:29: 
3) test eval 1 evals DottedList (sugared)
     expected: "((1 2) . 1)"
      but got: "Parse error at \"lisp\" (line 1, column 9):\nunexpected \".\"\nexpecting spaces' or parseExpr!"
```

Update:
From @pat's response, I got my tests to pass using:

```
parseExpr :: Parser LispVal
parseExpr = {- omitted -}
         <|> do char '('
                x <- many1 (do e <- parseExpr; spaces'; return e)
               {- omitted -}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sepBy` parser is seeing the space before the dot, and committing to parse another expression, which fails.

You should have lexemes consume and discard trailing spaces (see parsec's `lexeme`) and change the `sepBy` to just `many1`.  The `optionMaybe` can then commit after seeing a dot, which would otherwise have required a `try`.